# Command line to export to text file (.TXT) directory listing in Dirprintok

Tags: command, export, autohotkey

In the GUI there is the export option and I can export a plain text file with all my needed attributes of all files in a given directory- like - Frame Height, Frame width, frame rate, length, size, data rate..

I am trying to automate this to export every day but I cannot find a way to trigger the export via command.  Anyone know a way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Autohotkey to write a script that sends the keystrokes you need to send to the program.  Something like:

```
^e::
   WinActivate, Dirprintok
   Send, !fe
return
```

Assuming `alt F` gets you to the "File" menu and `E` is the accelerator for "Export".

Anyways, should get you started . . .